# El middleware EXPRESS.URLENCODED () me retorna undefined

Tags: nodejs, express

Hola tengo un problema con `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`, y es que cuando hago la peticion desde `POSTMAN`, consola de VSC, el `request.body` en mi controlador me bota un `undefined`

```
index.js
app.use('/users', users)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())

users router
router.post('/create', userController.createUser)

users controller
const createUser = (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body)
}

en mi POSTMAN
METODO: POST: localhost:3000/users/create
BODY: x-www-form-urlenconded
DATOS: 
id: 1
nombre: pepe
apellido: lope
```

Comment: intenta agregando en el header de la peticion `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Lo que me funciono fue poner un body-parser en una constante y pasarlo a mi metodo POST como un argumento en mi archivo userController.js

```const parserJson = require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: false});
router.post('/create', parserJson ,userController.createUser);```